# Spring boot admin with docker resolves docker hostnames and IPs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-admin

### My Issue/Setup

I'm trying to build a stand-alone spring boot admin application which all our instances (in a private VPC- behind a network load balancer) can register with. 
But my spring boot application itself runs inside a docker container, so hostname and ip-address always defaults to the container hostname and container ip-address.
And spring-boot admin fails with

```
`Request failed with status code 502`
Connection refused: /1XX.17.0.2:8840
```

because it cannot find actual hosts with the hostname or the IP addres.

### What i tried

I had the set up working with below (one instance),

```
`spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url`
```

But cannot use this for multiple clients as i cannot specify a comma separated value.

Moreover, since there can be `n` number of instance at any time i do not want to use the below property.

```
`spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url`
```

So i took the suggestion to omit `spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url` on spring-boot-admin git hub page and issues section and used below instead

```
`spring.boot.admin.client.instance.prefer-ip=true`
```

But Since my applications are running inside a docker container, 
spring boot clients register itself with container id/ip-address as the hostname/ip-address.

I also tried the `"--net=admin-network","--name client"` parameters in my AWS beanstalk file

```
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "cloudy-email",
      "image": "xxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sba-admin-repo:xx_2019-04-24_14.36_e9aax8710",
      "command": [ "--net=admin-network","--name client"],
      "Update": "true",
```

How can i overcome this issue?
Any pointers/references would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which docker command are you using?

Comment: I'm actually using a google plugin called `JIB` to create an image. It is way faster than using traditional docker image creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make docker run in the host network using the `--network host` option to the `docker run` command. This will make the container assume the same IP address of the host VM. Also, check if you are exposing the admin port through Docker and the host firewall (security groups).

More info: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: I will check this and let you know if that helped, thank you!.

Comment: Just updated the post with one other thing i tried.
I tried parameters `"--net=admin-network","--name client"` to see if they helped, but did not, but will try with your suggestion today.